# How to select group member count and follow status in same query mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get user's groups which he either created or following, along with the total number of followers and want to get the most recent follower's date so I can order by with that. I have two tables 
**groups**

```
id  title   creator_id   created
4   test3   123          1224322344
5   test2   213          2342344444
```

**follow**

```
id  to_id  follower_id   is_group   created
1    4       222             1       234324324
1    4       123             1       444234234
1    5       213             1       234234444
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT g. * , IFNULL(f.total_followers, 0 ) total_followers 
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT to_id, COUNT( * ) AS total_followers
    FROM follow
    WHERE is_group =1
    GROUP BY to_id
) AS f ON ( g.id = f.to_id ) 
where g.creator=123 
GROUP BY g.id
g.created DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But it only return me the number of followers of user's own groups not the groups he is following.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g.* , IFNULL(f.total_followers, 0 ) total_followers, f.most_recent
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT to_id, COUNT( * ) AS total_followers, MAX(created) AS most_recent
    FROM follow
    WHERE is_group =1
    GROUP BY to_id
) AS f ON ( g.id = f.to_id ) 
WHERE g.creator=123 
OR g.id in (SELECT to_id FROM follow WHERE follower_id = 123)
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Without using IN:

```
SELECT g.* , IFNULL(f.total_followers, 0 ) total_followers, f.most_recent
FROM (SELECT * FROM groups where creator = 123
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT g.* FROM groups AS g1
      JOIN follow AS f1 ON ( g1.id = f1.to_id)
      WHERE f1.follower_id = 123) AS g
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT to_id, COUNT( * ) AS total_followers, MAX(created) AS most_recent
    FROM follow
    WHERE is_group =1
    GROUP BY to_id
) AS f ON ( g.id = f.to_id )
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: in general never us the "in ("  clause. it is a performance dog

Comment: I will be grateful if there is any faster way to do this? Can I do it any other way than using in clause?

Comment: @DrewPierce Yeah, I usually try to avoid it. It's kind of a PITA for this query, because it's in an OR -- would have to add a subquery with a UNION.

Comment: as Barmar said. problem is when the "in (" hits a big table. it is fine for like "in ("CA","UT","TX)" and the like